# Emscripten - embind exported function not runs syncronously from Javascript. Using Asyncify

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I need to do a HTTP request to server, the result is JSON. The result is used in another C++ function which is exported using embind exports.

When call this exported function from js, it runs fast and cannot store value from exported function, value is empty, later in 2 seconds function is completed but value never was assigned.

**Steps to reproduce**

**1. My test/fake webapi**
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

---

**2. Mi JS Code - Instance.js**

```
window.VModule({ noInitialRun: false }).then(module => {
     window.VMain = {
          Module: module
     };
});

window.GetData = async function GetData() {
     try {
          var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/200"
          var options = {
               method: "GET",
               //mode: "cors",
               cache: "default"
          };
          var response = await fetch(new Request(url), options);
          var json = await response.json();
          console.log("DATA IN JS: " + json.title);
          return json.title;
     }
     catch (error) {
          console.log("DATA IN JS: ERROR_JS");
          return "ERROR_JS";
     }
}
```

---

**3. My C++ code - main.cpp** 
- EM_JS_GetData function who calls "window.GetData" defined in Instance.js
- GetData() calls EM_JS_GetData
window.GetData() -> EM_JS_GetData -> GetData() -> Button call from index.html.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
typedef std::string String;

EM_JS(const char *, EM_JS_GetData, (), {
    return Asyncify.handleSleep(function(wakeUp) {   
        window.GetData()
        .then(data=>{
            //Converting JsString to C-String
            var lengthBytes = lengthBytesUTF8(data)+1;
            var result = _malloc(lengthBytes);
            stringToUTF8(data, result, lengthBytes);
            wakeUp(result);
        })
    });
});

String GetData()
{
    try
    {
        const char *cstr = EM_JS_GetData();
        String result(cstr);
        free(static_cast<void*> (const_cast<char *>(cstr)));
        emscripten_console_log((u8"DATA IN C++: " + result).c_str());
        return result;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        emscripten_console_log(u8"DATA IN CPP: ERROR_CPP");
        return "ERROR_CPP";
    }
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    std::cout<< "All components initialized" << std::endl;       
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) 
{
    using namespace emscripten;
    function("GetData", &GetData);
}
```

---

**4. My compile command in power shell core syntax. - Compile.ps1**

```
em++.bat `
"main.cpp" `
-o "VModule.js" `
-std=c++17 `
-O2 `
--bind `
-s WASM=1 `
-s SINGLE_FILE=1 `
-s ASYNCIFY=1 `
-s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 `
-s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[`'ccall`',`'cwrap`'] `
-s EXPORT_NAME=`'VModule`' `
-s MODULARIZE=1 `
-s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 `
-s ENVIRONMENT=web `
-s ASYNCIFY_IMPORTS=[`'EM_JS_GetData`'] `
-s VERBOSE=0 `
```

---

**5. Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Validatos - WebAssembly</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Assets/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="VModule.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Instance.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="OnBtnClick()">Test</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnBtnClick() {
            console.log("BEFORE");
            var title = window.VMain.Module.GetData();//RESULT FROM FUNCTION IS NOT ASSIGNED // THIS LINE IS EXECUTED QUICKLY // BUT GetData is now executing.
            console.log("DATA IN INDEX.HTML: " + title);//console prints empty string, value was assigned to empty string. GetData continues executing.
            console.log("AFTER");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I clicked the button, I get following result.

```
All components initialized
(index):17 BEFORE
(index):19 DATA IN INDEX.HTML: 
(index):20 AFTER
Instance.js:19 DATA IN JS: ipsam aperiam voluptates qui
VModule.js:9 DATA IN C++: ipsam aperiam voluptates qui
```

[image]

how can I call syncronously window.VMain.Module.GetData()?
Desired behaviour

```
All components initialized
(index):17 BEFORE
Instance.js:19 DATA IN JS: ipsam aperiam voluptates qui
VModule.js:9 DATA IN C++: ipsam aperiam voluptates qui
(index):19 DATA IN INDEX.HTML: ipsam aperiam voluptates qui
(index):20 AFTER
```